# prove straight from the definition of convergence that (7n^2 -4)/(2n^2 + n +1) convergers to 7/2

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

i am stuck on finding a value for N, and how to simplify the equation in the absolute value

[this is the actual question, i am stuck need some help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEllf.png)

Comment: Please don't post links to images, but include your question here with proper typesetting. If you're stuck, it helps if you show your effort - where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

See my comment for future questions. Since you're new, here's a start.

With a few upper bounds, finding a suitable $N$ should not be too hard.

$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{7n^2-4}{2n^2+n+1}-\frac{7}{2}\right|
& = \left|-\frac{7n+15}{2\left(2n^2+n+1\right)}\right| \\[5pt]
& \le \left|\frac{\color{blue}{22n}}{2\left(2n^2\color{red}{+n+1}\right)}\right|  \\[5pt]
& \le \frac{22n}{2\left(2n^2\right)}  \\[5pt]
& = \frac{11}{2n}
\end{align}$$
You can easily make $\tfrac{11}{2n}$ arbitrary small by taking $n$ sufficiently large.